# Dropdown List bingding of State and City through database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created two tables for States and City respectively. Is there any easy way of binding the state table in a dropdown list and on selecting the state I should get the respective city on the next(city) dropdown. I have Already given StateID to the City Table for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
dropdownlistID.DataSource = table;
dropdownlistID.DataValueField = "ValueColumnName";
dropdownlistID.DataTextField = "TextColumnName";
dropdownlistID.DataBind();
```

where `dropdowlistID` is your dropdownlist's control ID and `table` is the table of states or cities.

Comment: can u ellaborate more specifically please..Thanks

Comment: If you don't post your code, I can't be more specific. Posting your code either works or not, we will have a common base on which can communicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, Actually I was getting the Databind() error. Which I resolved it. Anyways thanks

Comment: You welcome dude. I am glad that I could help.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from States_agri", conn); SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddl_state.DataSource = dr;         ddl_state.Items.Clear(); ddl_state.Items.Add("--Please Select state--");            ddl_state.DataTextField = "StateName";
            ddl_state.DataValueField = "StateID";
            ddl_state.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
I am unable to show the default value on the dropdown,can u help?

Comment: @NadeemKhan please post this code on another answer, in order to be more easy to follow up with the code and let me know to check it out (sending me the corresponding link). Thank you

Comment: christos: thanks for your patience in the past. Learned many things now :) i was just looking at my past question post and was wondering about it :P

Comment: @nkb You are very welcome ! I am glad about hearing this :)